# lubuntu, make the terminals / some windows, to not stack in the task bar

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, taskbar

I usually have several terminals open and want to access them quickly.

But the terminal stacking makes it kinda hard. Is it possible to make the terminals not stack?

[image]

i'm on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Unfortunately with the setting you can only have either stacked all apps or none.  You might find it quicker to access the terminal windows through Alt+Tab when jumping between them instead of clicking on them on the bar.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can show the terminals individually on the task bar.

1. Right-click the task bar area
2. Select Task Bar/ Window List Settings
3. Uncheck the "Combine multiple application windows into a single
   button" setting

[image]

Mine looks like this (using Numix Circle icons) when I have 2 terminal windows open.

[image]

I have "icons only" checked, if you want the descriptive text, uncheck that.